# Divisibility of orders and finite abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ and $G$ be an abelian group with $|G| =
>  m$. Furthermore we assume that $x^n = 1$ for any $x \in G$. Prove that
>   $m$ divides a power of $n$.

What I know is that since $G$ is a finite group, we have that $x^m = 1$ for any $x \in G$. But somehow I do not quite see how to proceed. Has anyone a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime dividing $m$. By Cauchy's theorem, $G$ has an element $x$ of order $p$, and since $x^n=1$ it follows that $p$ divides $n$.

Therefore every prime divisor of $m$ also divides $n$, hence $m$ divides a sufficiently large power of $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be honest, we did not yet cover Cauchy's theorem in class. Is there an alternative approach? Still +1

Comment: Perhaps induction on $m$? For the induction step, you could pick an element $x$ of $G$, and either $G=\langle x\rangle$ which reduces things to the cyclic case which should be easy, or else $G/\langle x\rangle$ is a group of smaller order.

Comment: I have just seen, that the second part of the exercise askes to prove Cauchy's theorem for finite abelian groups. Therefore I may use it. Thanks. Why does exactly the second statement hold?

Comment: If $m=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ for primes $p_1,\dots,p_k$, then we have shown that $n$ must have the form $n=p_1^{b_1}\cdots p_k^{b_k}r$, where $r$ is coprime to $p_1,\dots,p_k$. If you choose an integer $d$ large enough that $db_j\geq a_j$ for all $j$, then $m$ divides $n^d$.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks again.